Error when using service account json key file from secrets manager in dbt cloud build pipeline step
I'm running a cloud build pipeline to deploy my dbt data pipelines project. In one of the steps I'm trying to execute dbt compile which tests a connection to BigQuery. I get the error: dbt was unable to connect to the specified database. The database returned the following error: Database Error Invalid control character at: line 1 column 174 (char 173). The credentials are being accessed from google cloud secrets manager. Here is my cloudbuild.yaml file:
steps:
  # Step 1: Run terraform init and apply commands
  - id: "terraform"
    name: "hashicorp/terraform"
    entrypoint: "sh"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        mkdir -p credentials && echo $$creds > credentials/google.json && cd ./terraform && terraform init \
        && terraform workspace select dev && terraform apply -auto-approve -lock=false
    secretEnv:
      - "creds"
  # Step 2: Execute the dbt compile command
  - id: "dbt compile"
    name: "ghcr.io/dbt-labs/dbt-bigquery:1.5.0"
    entrypoint: "sh"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        mkdir -p /credentials && echo $$creds > /credentials/google.json \
        && dbt compile --project-dir dbt --profiles-dir dbt --target dev
    secretEnv:
      - "creds"

timeout: 2000s

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/[project_id]/secrets/[secret_name]/versions/1
      env: "creds"

When I run the dbt compile command locally, using the exact same service account json key file, but stored locally, everything runs successfully. Is something happening when it's being stored/retrieved from secrets manager that is changing some characters is there a way to prevent this?
I've tried to locate the invalid control character mentioned in the error message but I'm not sure I was doing this correctly - any advice here would be appreciated.
Edit: Here is my dbt profiles.yml file:
# profiles.yml

bigquery_connection:
  target: dev
  
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: bigquery
      method: service-account
      project: [project_id]
      dataset: transform
      threads: 1
      timeout_seconds: 300
      location: EU
      keyfile: /credentials/google.json


drive-by comment with associated caveats because I'm entirely unfamiliar with dbt albeit familiar with Cloud Build. You could add a statement to  "Step 2" to more /credentials/google.json to verify that it's created as expected. How does the dbt access the credentials that you create? You create the google.json file from $$creds but this doesn't appear to be reflected in the dbt command that follows. Is there a reason to use credentials in "Step 1" but /credentials in "Step 2"? That it works in the first step, suggests the file is created correctly.

You could share the credentials between steps using the /workspace folder. See Passing data between build steps

Hi @DazWilkin, I've printed the json using the cat command and it looks fine. With dbt you have a profiles.yml file where you put the path to the credentials file, which I've added above. The reason for using credentials in step 1, but /credentials in step 2 is purely just to match the directory structure in my local directory and ensure the profiles.yml path works both locally and in cloud build.
